# Convert MySQL now() based on timezone of rows being searched

Tags: mysql, timezone

Suppose I have data in a table "events" structured like this:

```
eventid  | datetime_start      | datetime_end        | timezone  
001      | 2016-01-01 10:00:00 | 2016-01-01 14:00:00 | America/Los_Angeles
002      | 2016-01-03 19:00:00 | 2016-01-03 22:00:00 | America/Los_Angeles
003      | 2016-01-17 02:00:00 | 2016-01-17 06:00:00 | America/New_York
004      | 2016-01-31 23:00:00 | 2016-02-01 01:00:00 | America/Los_Angeles
```

The timezone column allows dates/times to be stored exactly as entered rather than normalized to UTC, GMT, etc.

I want to query the table to find eventids where "now()" falls between datetime_start and datetime_end:

```
SELECT eventid FROM events WHERE now() BETWEEN datetime_start AND datetime_end
```

However, since "now()" is based on a fixed timezone (UTC in my case), is there any way to convert "now()" to match the timezone column row by row as it searches? Maybe something in the spirit of the following:

```
SELECT eventid FROM events WHERE CONVERT_TZ(now(),'UTC',timezone) BETWEEN datetime_start
AND datetime_end
```

Comment: You query seems correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I was just guessing at the query syntax and assumed it was incorrect. Sure enough: `Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'timezone' in 'where clause'`

Comment: My mistake. No error in the query. I mistyped it. Still didn't match rows where it should have. Are you sure my query syntax is correct?

Comment: What's the data type here?

Comment: data types for datetime_start and datetime_end are both datetime.

Comment: wow, it works! the query syntax i pulled out of thin air in my original question was actually correct (very LUCKY guess, i assure you), and something else i'd done wrong was causing it to return no results. thanks for the vote of confidence, dylan su!